# How do i remove files from the Pending Changes list in TFS when those files have been deleted locally

Tags: tfs

as the question says...does anyone know how I can remove these files? I didn't commit the changes in TFS before I deleted them locally and now they always appear in the Pending Changes window...I'd like to get rid of them

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved

I recreated the deleted folder and files in TFS and checked them in. Then I deleted them and they were gone from the Pending changes window.

Answer (score 62):

Right-click on the file in the Pending Changes List, choose **Undo**.

Comment: it can't find the file to undo the changes because I have deleted it

Comment: believe it or not I actually had this same exact problem. I also didn't have the files.  I right-clicked "view pending changes" on the solution and it pulled up all of the pending changes to my deleted files.  I then selected them all, and right-clicked undo. It worked!

Comment: @kurasa you might have been in the wrong workspace therefore not seeing the correct list of files

Comment: Worked for me, I had lots of backup files from an upgrade that had been checked in to source, i deleted them to clean up the project then there were 1000 items that could not be checked in due to not being there.

Comment: "Undo" is kind of misleading, since really the changes have been undone in the version you're working with.

Answer (score 3):

It's simpler than that.  Just select the deleted file(s) and right click and select Check-in.  Files will be "checked-in" and deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Go to show all files.
The deleted files will be shown.
Delete them.
Done.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a large amount of files, and it's hard to tell which files have been deleted, and which haven't, it's best to backup the files and undo all changes. After this, you can re-add the files and VS will finally refresh the list.