# Convert gitignore file to tfignore. From a default ionic app I started

Tags: git, ionic-framework

How can I convert the following gitignore file to a tfignore file. I use TFS for source control and don't want to check these files in as the directory is very large

Here is the gitignore file:

```
# Specifies intentionally untracked files to ignore when using Git
# http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

*~
*.sw[mnpcod]
*.log
*.tmp
*.tmp.*
log.txt
*.sublime-project
*.sublime-workspace
.vscode/
npm-debug.log*

.idea/
.sourcemaps/
.sass-cache/
.tmp/
.versions/
coverage/
dist/
node_modules/
tmp/
temp/
hooks/
platforms/
plugins/
plugins/android.json
plugins/ios.json
www/
$RECYCLE.BIN/

.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the [tfignore man page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/add-files-server?view=vsts)

> ### `.tfignore` file rules
>
> The following rules apply to a `.tfignore` file:
>
> - `#` begins a comment line
> - The `*` and `?` wildcards are supported.
> - A filespec is recursive unless prefixed by the `\` character.
> - `!` negates a filespec (files that match the pattern are not ignored)
>
> `.tfignore` file example

```
######################################
# Ignore .cpp files in the ProjA sub-folder and all its subfolders
ProjA\*.cpp
#
# Ignore .txt files in this folder
\*.txt
#
# Ignore .xml files in this folder and all its sub-folders
*.xml
#
# Ignore all files in the Temp sub-folder
\Temp
#
# Do not ignore .dll files in this folder nor in any of its sub-folders
!*.dll
```

That does not look that much different from your `.gitignore` (except for the '`/`' which is '`\`'): try a simple copy-paste into your `.tfignore`, and see if the unwanted files still show up in the Pending change list or not: [you can still undo those changes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770727/6309), tweak your `.tfignore` file, and try again.